# Proving that a set is not closed or closed

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble formally proving that a certain set is open, closed, or not open or not closed. How do I prove that a set of the form (a,b] is not closed , and one of the form [a,b] is closed, using the general definitions ?

Comment: Honestly, it depends on your definition of closed:  there are at least three ways of doing it.

Comment: The only thing I know about closed sets it is that they are  closed if  R\ the set is open, and that leads to the next question : it is ok to prove that a set is not closed if the R\ the set is not open?

Comment: So your subsets of $\Bbb R$ are closed if the complement in $\Bbb R$ is open. So for $[a,b]$ can you show that $(-\infty,a)\cup(b,\infty)$ is open?

Comment: OK, then $[a,b]$ is closed because its complement is $(-\infty, a) \cup (b, +\infty)$ is open.  Carry on...

Comment: If by closed, you mean "contains all of its limit points" then Michael has produced a justification below, which you should be able to turn into a proof.

Comment: In order to prove that the reunion is open I must prove that the sets are open and their reunion is open , but how do I develop a formal proof using neighbourhood  and balls ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(a+\frac{b-a}{n}\right)=a,$$ but $a\not\in(a,b]$ and for all natural $n$ we have
$$a+\frac{b-a}{n}\in(a,b],$$ which says that $(a,b]$ is not closed.

Comment: Thank you , but I'm not supposed to use limits :)

Comment: @Alex For all $\epsilon>0$ we have $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\cap(a,b]\neq\oslash$, but $a\not\in(a,b]$.

Comment: @Alex12 Okay, you are not supposed to use limits. But answerers are not supposed to read your mind. Edit the question to state the definition of "closed" that you have.

Comment: Thanks  everyone , I think I managed  , sorry for any misunderstandings !

Comment: @Alex12 You are welcome!